# Apache web server issue

Tags: apache2.4

Before adding the certificate I could access the following site

http://website.com:4043/web/login

But after adding the certificate I can't access the full URL with https.
I can however access only https://website.com

Any support please.

Comment: when add the mentioned code the following error appear :cannot define multiple listeners on the same ip:port @matigo

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running a modern version of Ubuntu, you will want to ensure your Apache virtual configuration file looks something like this:

```
Listen 443
Listen 4043

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName website.com

    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:4043>
    ServerName website.com

    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

From here, you can set up a quick little `.htaccess` rule to ensure that traffic is properly redirected to `4043` rather than the server default of `443`. For example:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If the port isn't 4043
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^4043$

# We redirect to the same address with the proper port
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}:4043/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**IMPORTANT:** Do not simply copy and paste this stuff. Look at the text and make adjustments for your own environment, which is unknown to everyone *except* you.

Comment: when add the mentioned code the following error appear :cannot define multiple listeners on the same ip:port

Comment: Note the "important" bit. Also note that your question leaves *a lot* of detail out. Hence the "do not simply copy and paste" message. If you would like a more specific solution, please provide more specific information.

Comment: The `:4043` thing probably is some kind of control panel and probably it is served by another application (not Apache). In that case we can use Apache as reverse proxy and pass `website.com/web/login` to `127.0.0.1:4043/web/login` or something like this... @Walid?

Comment: I did it and working but after login redirected to another directory as follow http://e127.0.0.1/web with error 404 not found , The requested URL was not found on this server, please support me.